# Can an isotope emit only Beta radiation? Or is gamma radiation always emitted alongside beta?

Tags: radiation, isotopes

[image: This confused me]

If so, what isotopes only emit beta radiation?

Thanks!

Comment: found by google http://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~blanchar/purebeta.htm